# Mysql didint give back any rows

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is, that i didnt get any products from mysql. If i echo out the sql query, i get back 3 rows, and thats fine, because, i have 3 products in the ID-12 category.

If echo out the $category_id, and i get: 12

Whats wrong with my code? I didnt get any erros.

Thank you!

```
<?php
function render_category_page($category_id)
{
    $id = (int)$this->$category_id;
    $connect_to_mysql = my_conn();

    if($connect_to_mysql == true )
    {
        get_product_data("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = '".$id."'", $connect_to_mysql, $limit = 0);
        if(get_product_data())
        {
            if(count_rows_of_sql(get_product_data) == 0 )
            {
                show_message("There are no rows in the table.");
            }
            else
            {
                show_message("There are '".count_rows_of_sql(get_product_data)."' rows in the table.");

                $product = fetch_data_from_sql(get_product_data());

                $category_id            = (int)$product['category_id'];
                $product_name           = "<h1 class='product_name'>".cut_html_chars($product['product_name'])."</h1>";
                $product_desricption    = "<p class='product_desricption'>".cut_html_chars($product['product_desricption'])."</p>";
                $product_full_content   = "<div class='product_full_content'>".cut_html_chars($product['product_full_content'])."</div>";
                $product_to_link        = "<a href='".$this->$product_to_link."' class='product_to_link' title='".$this->$product_name."' target='_self'>".$this->$product['product_seo_url']."</a>";

                for($i = 1; $i <= count_rows_of_sql(get_product_data); $i++)
                {
                    $i++;
                }

                $products_in_category = (int)products_in_category($i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log_message("The sql command didnt run.", $type = "sql", $write_to_file = 1);
            write_error_message_to_file("./logs/error_logs/", $filename = $type . "-error" . date("Y-m-d-H:i:s") . generate_random_number($min = 1, $max = 9999), $fileType = "txt");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        log_message("Cant connect to database.", $type = "sql", $write_to_file = 1);
        write_error_message_to_file("./logs/error_logs/", $filename = $type . "-error" . date("Y-m-d-H:i:s") . generate_random_number($min = 1, $max = 9999), $fileType = "txt");
    }
}
render_page($page_type = "category", $html = 1, $template = "bootsrap-4", $pagination = $products_in_category, $product_container_div  = "product-container", render_category_page($category_id));
?>
```

Comment: How is get_product_data defined? Its a function, but sometimes value?

Comment: You're using a lot of functions here, and without seeing those, its impossible for us to say where it fails. You're probably making it way to complex here.

Comment: A cucumber, or what do you mean?

Comment: You are casting `$category_id` to an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are making too many functions. & making a couple of mistakes in them.
After seeing your code, I can understand:

- `get_product_data()` needs couple of arguments
- `get_product_data()` returns some data

You have two problems in your code:

- `get_product_data("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = '".$id."'", $connect_to_mysql, $limit = 0);`
  the result of query execution is not saved in any variable, making it useless.
- `if(get_product_data())` , here no arguments are passed, thus your code enters the body of `else` code

Here's what you need to do , either

- saving the query result in a variable, & then use that variable to check the `if` condition. Something like this:

  `$result 1 = get_product_data("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = '".$id."'", $connect_to_mysql, $limit = 0);
  if($result1) {
  ...`
- or, you can combine the two statements in one line like this: 
  `if(get_product_data("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id =
  '".$id."'", $connect_to_mysql, $limit = 0)) { ...`

Hope this helps you to understand your mistake.